# XAMPP wordpress on localhost

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I have this site and I need to test it out locally to see if there is an issue with my php settings, anyways I tried to navigate to localhost with the port number `localhost:portnumber`
and that worked fine, but then I tried to navigate to my site `localhost:portnumber/mysite` and I get a 404 error and the in the the address i navigate to changes to `localhost:portnumber/mysite`

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `http://127.0.0.1/sitename` with or /w port number ?

Comment: yea i tried that, it didnt work, I even tried with the port number, i got a 404 error when I tried without the port and with the port

Comment: Do you have **Skype** working in the mean time ?

Comment: I have Skype but its not open

Comment: Skype can block `80` port if in _Connection config_ is set to _Use `80` and `443` ports as alternative_. If Skype is launched with this option port `80` will be blocked and XAMPP (_in this case_) will be unable to launch `Apache`.

Comment: What `port` are you using to access your server ? What configuration of XAMPP are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are getting a 404 error, your server seems to be running but make sure the server is the one you have setup.

1st, have you tried using a simple html file? example: `blabla.html` on root, and typing: `localhost:portnumber/blabla.html`

If this is working, that means your server is running fine, you can also try with an Hello world php file if you wish.

In the case of wordpress, there is sometime a `.htaccess` file that uses url rewrite and it may remove your port number, you could try to test with a clean wordpress install first.

Comment: ahhh after looking at the .htaccess file there is this `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>` Should I remove that?

Comment: The server is working because I have used magento on my localhost with the port number

Comment: I removed the code above from my .htacess and it goes to the right url but nothing shows up.